# jQuery show() is not working properly

Tags: jquery, list, expand

I have an issue regarding expanding the child content of a li tag in jquery. My content is :

```
<ul id="0" class="set_preference">
    <li class="1stlevel">1st-Entertainment
        <ul>
            <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-Films
                <ul>
                    <li class="3rdlevel">3rdTollywood
                        <ul>
                            <li class="4thlevel">
                             <input type="checkbox" value="58" name="checkChild[]" class1="checkChild css-checkbox" id="cat_58">Bhooter bhabishyat</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="3rdlevel">3rdbollywood
                        <ul>
                            <li class="4thlevel">4th<input type="checkbox" value="60" name="checkChild[]" class1="checkChild css-checkbox" id="cat_60">krish</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="3rdlevel">3rdHollywood
                        <ul>
                            <li class="4thlevel">4th<input type="checkbox" value="62" name="checkChild[]" class1="checkChild css-checkbox" id="cat_62">Spiderman</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-Television
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="1stlevel">1st-Celebrities
        <ul>
            <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-Film
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-Music
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-Public Life
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-Sports
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-Others
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-<input type="checkbox" value="18" name="checkChild[]" class1="checkChild css-checkbox" id="cat_18">Television
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="1stlevel">1st-Sports
        <ul>
            <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-Badminton
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-Cricket
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-Soccer
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-Tennis
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="1stlevel">1st-Music
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="1stlevel">1st-Brands
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="1stlevel">1st-Cartoons
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and I am trying in jquery like:

```
$j('.1stlevel').click(function(){
            $j('.2ndlevel').show();
            $j(this).children().css({"border":"1px solid red"});
//            $j(this).find('ul li').hide();
        });
        $j('.2ndlevel').click(function(){
            $j('.3rdlevel').show();
            $j(this).children().css({"border":"1px solid pink"});
//            $j(this).find('ul li').hide();
//            $j(this).find('ul li').hide();
        });
        $j('3rdlevel').click(function(){
            $j('.4thlevel').show();
            $j(this).children().css({"border":"1px solid green"});
//            $j(this).find('ul li ul li').hide();
            //$j(this).find('ul li').hide();
        });
        $j('.4thlevel').click(function(){
            $j(this).children().css({"border":"1px solid red"});
//            $j(this).find('ul li').hide();
        });
    });
```

But when I click on any level, next children of other tag is also opening. But my expectation is if I click on `3rdTollywood` then `Bhooter bhabishyat` should open but neither `krish` nor `Spiderman`
Please help me.

http://jsfiddle.net/9wnqj1dz/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9wnqj1dz/ - Syntax errors, please fix

Comment: @Nandha Kumar: They obviously are using `$j` as an alias for `jQuery`

Comment: +1 @NandhaKumar its just an alias, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Here is a starting jSFiddle for all to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9wnqj1dz/3/

Comment: @Edward k i given one code try that

Comment: @NandhaKumar, lovely, i'd address it to the OP tho ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using class selectors you're matching any element of that class, not only the descendants of the element that received the click.
One method to implement your needs is to use [jQuery.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to filter `$(this)` descendants.

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mx20vj42/1/)

Comment: You are still expanding all the lists, not just the one selected.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I did it only for 3d level to 4th :)

Comment: This is fine but if I click 1stlevel then all child having 2ndlevel is opening. But it is not expected. exact child only will open.

Answer (score 1):

I remaned the classes to `_1stlevel`, etc. for this example, since technically [classes shouldn't begin with a digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors).

Use `.find()` to select elements under the clicked element.

```js
$j = jQuery;

$j('._1stlevel').click(function(){
            $j(this).find('._2ndlevel').show();
            $j(this).children().css({"border":"1px solid red"});
        });
        $j('._2ndlevel').click(function(){
            $j(this).find('._3rdlevel').show();
            $j(this).children().css({"border":"1px solid pink"});
        });
        $j('_3rdlevel').click(function(){
            $j(this).find('._4thlevel').show();
            $j(this).children().css({"border":"1px solid green"});
        });
        $j('._4thlevel').click(function(){
            $j(this).children().css({"border":"1px solid red"});
        });
```

```css
._2ndlevel, ._3rdlevel, ._4thlevel {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="_0" class="set_preference">
    <li class="_1stlevel">1st-Entertainment
        <ul>
            <li class="_2ndlevel">2nd-Films
                <ul>
                    <li class="_3rdlevel">3rdTollywood
                        <ul>
                            <li class="_4thlevel">
                             <input type="checkbox" value="_58" name="checkChild[]" class1="checkChild css-checkbox" id="cat_58">Bhooter bhabishyat</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="_3rdlevel">3rdbollywood
                        <ul>
                            <li class="_4thlevel">4th<input type="checkbox" value="_60" name="checkChild[]" class1="checkChild css-checkbox" id="cat_60">krish</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="_3rdlevel">3rdHollywood
                        <ul>
                            <li class="_4thlevel">4th<input type="checkbox" value="_62" name="checkChild[]" class1="checkChild css-checkbox" id="cat_62">Spiderman</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="_2ndlevel">2nd-Television
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="_1stlevel">1st-Celebrities
        <ul>
            <li class="_2ndlevel">2nd-Film
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="_2ndlevel">2nd-Music
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="_2ndlevel">2nd-Public Life
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="_2ndlevel">2nd-Sports
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="_2ndlevel">2nd-Others
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="_2ndlevel">2nd-<input type="checkbox" value="_18" name="checkChild[]" class1="checkChild css-checkbox" id="cat_18">Television
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="_1stlevel">1st-Sports
        <ul>
            <li class="_2ndlevel">2nd-Badminton
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="_2ndlevel">2nd-Cricket
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="_2ndlevel">2nd-Soccer
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="_2ndlevel">2nd-Tennis
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="_1stlevel">1st-Music
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="_1stlevel">1st-Brands
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="_1stlevel">1st-Cartoons
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Leading digits in IDs are fine for HTML5 (just not good for HTML 4), so good sugguestion.

Comment: Got some typos in there stopping you from getting to level 4. `$j('3rdlevel')` => `$j('._3rdlevel')`

Comment: Thank you Paul for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you

```
      HTML:
      <li class="1stlevel">1st-Sports
      <ul class="ww">
        <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-Badminton
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-Cricket
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-Soccer
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="2ndlevel">2nd-Tennis
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul> 

     CSS:

     .ww
      {
       display:none;
      }

     jquery:

      $('.1stlevel').click(function(){   
        $('.ww').css('display','block');           
      });
```